# Obtaining the logical pixel width of any character in visual studio editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-sdk

I'm making an editor extension for VS2012, and I need to find the logical pixel width of any character in the editor.

I think that all characters share the same width, but the shared width changes as the zoom amount of the editor changes; when the zoom is at 100%, all characters are 7 logical pixels wide, otherwise they're all 7.33 logical pixels wide.

I can find the width of any character by writing:
 

    `// textview is an ITextView 

    textview.Caret.ContainingTextViewLine.TextWidth /
 textview.Caret.ContainingTextViewLine.Length`

However, the problem is when the line that the caret is on is empty, since that would be a division by zero.

Comment: Couldn't you just simulate a space, get width, and simulate delete of space, when you want the width?

Comment: yea I could, but it seems like a hack. it's my last resort.

Comment: Use textwidth function ..

Comment: If you can get the Font which the editor uses, you can use `TextRenderer.MeasureText`

Comment: i fixed my problem without finding an answer to this question. should i close this question?

Comment: @daniel1426 add your solution as an answer in case anyone else might want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find an answer to my question, but I found a solution to my problem:

```
VirtualSnapshotPoint Get_point(ITextCaret caret)
    {
    caret.ContainingTextViewLine.GetInsertionBufferPositionFromXCoordinate(...);
    }
```

That method made it unnecessary for me to work with the logical pixel width of any character.